# Hiding mobile browser searchbar by using mobile app meta tags?

Tags: php, header, meta-tags, mobile-application, mobile-browser

Okay so I know that things like scrollTo doesnt work anymore.

But I found an idea to use meta tags to make any browser believe that your website is a mobile app and because of that hiding the searchbar on pageload.

My take on this was to add the tags to the functions.php.

I tried this code:

```
// Add custom meta tags to the head section of the website
function add_custom_meta_tags_to_head() {
?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="path/to/icon.png">
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_custom_meta_tags_to_head');
// Add custom meta tags to the head section of the website
```

but somehow it it doesnt work.

Now is the question is my code wrong or is this method another dead end?

With kind regards
Chris

Comment: Are you using any Php framework?

Comment: Are you using any Php framework?